# PDF-XChange Viewer, pdflatex, Windows XP Pro SP3

Tags: windows-xp, vim, pdf, pdf-reader, pdflatex

Howto make `pdfxcview.exe` not lock PDF files when opening them

**or**

force `pdflatex` ignore locks (and thus be able to overwrite PDF while generating content with pdflatex or simply manipulating content (streams) of PDF files manually with an editor like `vim`) ?

See also this [thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/21335/vim-pdf-xchange-pdflatex-tex-live-2010-windows-xp-pdfsync/21337#21337)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PDF-XChange View supports a command line option

```
pdfxcview /A "nolock=yes=OpenParameters" document.pdf
```

which opens a PDF file called `document.pdf` lock - free. In this case PDF-XChange View asks on change if the document should be reloaded. You can then enable automatic reloading on change. Useful when working on PDF files and **frequently** checking created output.

Comment: It's not ideal: (a) can't globally start pdfxcview in that mode. Have to provide that flag together with the filename of the document. And (b) the viewer will only reload when it gets focus.